# update mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to update to mysqli some code that was mysql. How can I say now: if there is something selected ...

php.net says that mysql_num_rows is deprecated and give other alternatives to this function that seems more complicated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

After trying a lot of things, I discover that if I just add a "i", this works. Is it correct or there is a better solution?. If it is so easy, why php.net does not even mention it? :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        // do something 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking to many people it seems that this is correct. It seems that php.net accept mysqli_num_rows: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

I still don't understand why they does not say that mysqli_num_rows is correct when you look at  mysql_num_rows. : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php . They send you to other solutions This can make a lot of confusions.

Anyway, I think, this works and it is the updated mysqli:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        // do something 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the manual: [fetch-assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) & [num-rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT ColumnList FROM client";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query) && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    ...
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```